# While loop causing issues with CSV read

Tags: python, csv, while-loop

Everything was going fine until I tried to combine a while loop with a CSV read and I am just unsure where to go with this.

The code that I am struggling with:

```
airport = input('Please input the airport ICAO code: ')

with open('airport-codes.csv', encoding='Latin-1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if airport.lower() == row[0].lower():
            airportCode = row[2] + "/" + row[0]
            print(airportCode)
        else:
            print('Sorry, I don\'t recognise that airport.')
            print('Please try again.')
```

Executing this code causes the 'else' to print continuously until the code is stopped, regardless of whether or not the input matches that in the CSV file. The moment I remove this statement the code runs fine (albeit doesn't print anything if the input doesn't match).

What I am aiming to try and do is have the question loop until true. So my attempt was as follows:

```
with open('airport-codes.csv', encoding='Latin-1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        while True:
            airport = input('Please input the airport ICAO code: ')
            if airport.lower() == row[0].lower():
                airportCode = row[2] + "/" + row[0]
                print(airportCode)
                break
            else:
                print('Sorry, I don\'t recognise that airport.')
                print('Please try again.')
                False
```

I'm pretty sure my limited experience is causing me to oversee an obvious issue but I couldn't find anything similar with my search queries so my next stop was here.

As requested, a few lines of the CSV file:

```
EDQO    small_airport   OttengrÃ¼ner Heide Airport  50.22583389, 11.73166656    
EDQP    small_airport   Rosenthal-Field PlÃ¶ssen Airport    49.86333466, 
EDQR    small_airport   Ebern-Sendelbach Airport    50.03944397, 10.82277775    
EDQS    small_airport   Suhl-Goldlauter Airport 50.63194275, 10.72749996    
EDQT    small_airport   HaÃŸfurt-Schweinfurt Airport    50.01805496, 
EDQW    small_airport   Weiden in der Oberpfalz Airport 49.67890167,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it precisely your way, you just need to make sure your `csv` reader's pointer returns back to the beginning of the file when a user enters bad code, something like:

```
with open('airport-codes.csv', encoding='Latin-1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    airportCode = None  # store for our code
    while not airportCode:  # loop until valid code found
        airport = input('Please input the airport ICAO code: ')  # ask for the code
        for row in reader:  # loop through our CSV
            if airport.lower() == row[0].lower():  # if code found in the first column...
                airportCode = row[2] + "/" + row[0]
                break  # no need to search further
        if not airportCode:  # we didn't find the code, print a helpful message
            print('Sorry, I don\'t recognise that airport.')
            print('Please try again.')
            f.seek(0)  # reset the CSV pointer to the beginning for the next loop
    print("Airport found: {}".format(airportCode))
```

But I'd suggest you to just load your codes in memory and do quick lookups on the spot:

```
airportCode = None  # store for our code
airport_codes = {}  # our in-memory fast lookup
with open('airport-codes.csv', encoding='Latin-1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:  # loop through our CSV
        airport_codes[row[0].lower()] = row[2] + "/" + row[0]  # store the lookup map 
while not airportCode:
    airport = input('Please input the airport ICAO code: ')  # ask for the code
    airportCode = airport_codes.get(airport.lower(), None)
    if not airportCode:
        print('Sorry, I don\'t recognise that airport.')
        print('Please try again.')
print("Airport found: {}".format(airportCode))
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be something like this:

```
airport = input('Please input the airport ICAO code: ')

airportCode = None
with open('airport-codes.csv', encoding='Latin-1') as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if airport.lower() == row[0].lower():
            airportCode = row[2] + "/" + row[0]
            print(airportCode)
            break

if airportCode is not None:
    print('Sorry, I don\'t recognise that airport.')
    print('Please try again.')
```

Comment: This works if I set 'airportCode is None' however it doesn't revert to the original question, which is what a require.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different suggestion using functions:

```
import csv

def findAirportCode(airport):
    with open('airport-codes.csv', encoding='Latin-1') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:

                if airport.lower() == row[0].lower():
                    airportCode = row[2] + "/" + row[0]
                    return airportCode            
        return None


airport = input('Please input the airport ICAO code: ')
code = findAirportCode(airport)
if(code != None ):
    print (code)
else:
    print('Sorry, I don\'t recognise that airport.')
    print('Please try again.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to match each line in your CSV with the entered input, it is best to first read your whole CSV data into a Python dictionary. This then lets you easily "look up" any airport code you like without having to keep re-reading the whole file in:

```
import csv

airport_codes = {}

with open('airport-codes.csv', encoding='Latin-1', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')

    for row in csv_input:
        if len(row) >= 2:    # Make sure the CSV line has at least 2 columns
            airport_codes[row[0].lower()] = row[2]

while True:   
    icao_code = input('Please input the airport ICAO code: ').lower().strip()

    try:
        print("{}/{}".format(row[0], airport_codes[icao_code]))
    except KeyError:
        print("Sorry, I don't recognise airport.")
        print("Please try again.\n")
```

Doing it this way would allow your script to prompt for multiple questions.

Note: The data you have posted in your question appears to be tab delimited, if that is the case, `\t` is needed to read the entries correctly. It is also recommended to add `newline=''` to your `open()` statement if it is going to be used with a CSV reader as can be seen in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

The `try` and `except` is what is called exception handling, in this case if the entry you are looking for in the dictionary is not present, the code jumps to the `except` part. This is the preferred approach in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logical flow is just a little off. If you want to continue looping through the csv file until you find the airport code, and then print an error message if the code is not there, then we need to do things in a different order. Currently, the code loops through every line of the file. And for every line, if the input code does not match any airport codes in the csv file, it prints out the message that it isn't there. Instead, we want to print the error message if it's not in ANY of the lines. We also only want one prompt per entire loop through the csv file. Instead of this:

```
with open('airport-codes.csv', encoding='Latin-1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader: # Loop over every row in the csv
        while True: # This effectively keeps you in the loop until you 'break'
            airport = input('Please input the airport ICAO code: ')
            if airport.lower() == row[0].lower():
                airportCode = row[2] + "/" + row[0]
                print(airportCode)
                break # break if this row matches the airport code
            else:
                print('Sorry, I don\'t recognise that airport.')
                print('Please try again.') # Prints if this row doesn't match
                False # This doesn't set anything to 'False'
```

Try this:

```
with open('airport-codes.csv', encoding='Latin-1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    while True:
        matches = False
        airport = input('Please input the airport ICAO code:')
        for row in reader:
            if airport.lower() == row[0].lower():
                airportCode = row[2] + "/" + row[0]
                print(airportCode)
                matches = True
                break
        if not matches:
            print('Sorry, I don\'t recognise that airport.')
            print('Please try again.')
            False
```

With this code, the flow is different. First, ask for an airport code. Then check it against the file until either you reach the end of the file or you find a matching code. If the code is found in the file, print it out. If it wasn't found, print a message and ask the user for a new airport code again.

Comment: This has really helped me understand the flow, thank you, but it doesn't seem to execute correctly. A correct input prints the right response however goes back to asking the same question. An incorrect input gives the correct response but then no correct input afterwords triggers the correct part of the code.

Comment: @R.Tatum I think the issue was the location of where I set `matches` to `False`. I have edited above